# fail: Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition[0] Exception type: Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, microsoft-graph-sdks

I am getting this error every time I build my application:

```
fail: Microsoft.Identity.Web.TokenAcquisition[0]
      False MSAL 4.49.1.0 MSAL.NetCore .NET 7.0.0 Microsoft Windows 10.0.19043 Exception type: Microsoft.Identity.Client.MsalUiRequiredException
      , ErrorCode: user_null
      HTTP StatusCode 0
      CorrelationId

         at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.Silent.SilentRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.Silent.SilentRequest.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
         at Microsoft.Identity.Client.Internal.Requests.RequestBase.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
```

I am building upon this project: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-1-Call-MSGraph

Other than the error, the app is working fine except for another error previously mentioned (token not automatically refreshing after about an hour) here: [Microsoft graph token refresh azure app service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75030198/microsoft-graph-token-refresh-azure-app-service).
However, this problem seemed to be a bug with .net 7.

My Startup class:

```
public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        
        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            // Get the scopes from the configuration (appsettings.json)
            var initialScopes = Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' ');
            
            // Add sign-in with Microsoft
            services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))

                // Add the possibility of acquiring a token to call a protected web API
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)

                // Enables controllers and pages to get GraphServiceClient by dependency injection
                // And use an in memory token cache
                .AddMicrosoftGraph(Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                .AddDistributedTokenCaches();



            // Register AadService and PbiEmbedService for dependency injection
            services.AddScoped(typeof(AadService))
                    .AddScoped(typeof(PbiEmbedService))
                    .AddScoped(typeof(PowerBiServiceApi));

            services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
            {
                var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
                    .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
                    .Build();
                options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
            });

            // Enables a UI and controller for sign in and sign out.
            services.AddRazorPages()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
            
            // Session/cookie variables etc

            services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
            services.AddSession();
            
            
            // Loading appsettings.json in C# Model classes
            services.Configure<AzureAd>(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"))
                    .Configure<PowerBI>(Configuration.GetSection("PowerBI"));
            
            // Add the UI support to handle claims challenges
            services.AddServerSideBlazor()
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityConsentHandler();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
        {
            
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }
            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseSession();
            
            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllerRoute(
                    name: "default",
                    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });
        }
    }
```

Controller class:

```
[Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }
        private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

        public HomeController(IConfiguration configuration,
                                GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
            _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
        }
        [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]
        public Task<IActionResult> Index()
        {
            var graphUser = _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
            var datasource = Configuration["AzureDB:Datasource"];
            var username = Configuration["AzureDB:Username"];
            var password = Configuration["AzureDB:Password"];
            var database = Configuration["AzureDB:Database"];
            var user = new Userclass(graphUser.Result, datasource, username, password, database);
            Console.WriteLine(user.ProjectName);
            if (!user.ProjectName.IsNullOrEmpty())
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetString("MyProject", user.ProjectName);
            }else{
                
                /*HttpContext.Session.SetString("MyProject", "No Project");*/
            }
            
            /*var user = _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
            Console.WriteLine(user.Result.DisplayName);*/
            return Task.FromResult<IActionResult>(View());
        }
        [AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "DownstreamApi:Scopes")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Profile()
        {

            var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
            

            return View(user);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicating the issue happened in `TokenAcquisition`, but the sample link you shared doesn't have the method which used `TokenAcquisition`. So I'm not sure where and how the issue happened. I noticed that you used .net 7, so I also created a new .net 7 MVC application then follow the sample link to test and it worked. Here's what I did in my side.

First, adding `_LoginPartial.cshtml` in `Shared` folder, the content is completely copied from the sample, then adding this partial view into `_layout.cshtml`. Then adding configuration in appsettings.json. I set `https://localhost/signin-oidc` in Azure portal web app platform.

```
"AzureAd": {
    "Instance": "https://login.microsoftonline.com/",
    "Domain": "tenant_id",
    "TenantId": "tenant_id",
    "ClientId": "azure_ad_app_id",
    "ClientSecret": "azure_ad_app_client_secret",
    //"ClientCertificates": [
    //],
    // the following is required to handle Continuous Access Evaluation challenges
    //"ClientCapabilities": [ "cp1" ],
    "CallbackPath": "/signin-oidc"
  },
  "DownstreamApi": {
    "BaseUrl": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0",
    "Scopes": "user.read"
  }
```

Then modifying Program.cs, also adding `app.UseAuthentication();`.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web;
using Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration)
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' '))
                .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews(options =>
{
    var policy = new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder()
        .RequireAuthenticatedUser()
        .Build();
    options.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeFilter(policy));
}).AddMicrosoftIdentityUI();
```

Then in my Controller, adding `[Authorize]` attribute for the controller, and inject `graphsdk`,

```
private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;

public HomeController(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient)
{
    _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
{
    var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
    return View();
}
```

Packages I installed:

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="7.0.2" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.MicrosoftGraph" Version="1.25.10" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Identity.Web.UI" Version="1.25.10" />
```

By the way, I also test the `TokenAcquisition` in my Controller. It became like below. It still worked.

```
private readonly GraphServiceClient _graphServiceClient;
private readonly ITokenAcquisition _tokenAcquisition;

public HomeController(GraphServiceClient graphServiceClient, ITokenAcquisition tokenAcquisition)
{
    _graphServiceClient = graphServiceClient;
    _tokenAcquisition = tokenAcquisition;
}

[AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "user.read")]
public async Task<IActionResult> IndexAsync()
{
    var user = await _graphServiceClient.Me.Request().GetAsync();
    string[] scopes = new string[] { "user.read" };
    string accessToken = await _tokenAcquisition.GetAccessTokenForUserAsync(scopes);
    return View();
}
```

[image]

But if I removed `[AuthorizeForScopes(ScopeKeySection = "user.read")]` for the action method, I will meet error like this, this is due to the sign in operation happened after the Index action method without the attribute.

[image]

Comment: I provided Startup and Controller classes to my question. 
I don't use the tokenacquisition either(?).
Maybe my startup class is wrongly configured?
I am not using the _loginpartial from the sample.

Comment: PowerBiServiceApi class uses tokenacquisition but everything is working fine other than the error message on project build, and this service is not used before the user enters a pageview with embedded power bi visuals (not index or login).

Comment: how about using my `services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
                .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration)
                .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("DownstreamApi:Scopes")?.Split(' '))
                .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
                .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();` instead of your `services.AddAuthentication` ?

Comment: `services.AddMicrosoftIdentityWebAppAuthentication(builder.Configuration)
        .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(new string[] { "user.read" })
        .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
        .AddInMemoryTokenCaches();` can work for me as well.

Comment: Still getting the same error 

Comment: hmmm, do you know which line report the error? I think a screenshot is good.

Comment: Doesn't say. It only says fail: followed by the error message in the original post when I build the project.

Comment: error messages said `exception` but it happened when build?  ... sorry I never met it..